# FFMPEG convert FLV to MP4 and reduce filesize

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, wowza

i have a system that is recording live stream via Wowza. I get from Wowza a .flv file with the record. The problem is, 5 minutes file is near to 50mb big. But when i look at some TV-Series that you can download from the net, they are 20 minutes, in mp4 and just  like 150mb big. Whatever... Look, the stream input is like:

```
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://127.0.0.1/stream/test.stream':
Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 720x404 [PAR 1:1 DAR 180:101], 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0.1: Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16
```

FFmpeg  shows me something like this at the "session":

```
frame= 2721 fps= 27 q=-1.0 Lsize=   17188kB time=111.21 bitrate=1266.1kbits/s
```

Have you any idea how to use FFmpeg to convert the .FLV file in MP4 in same near to Quality but smaller filesize?

btw. i'm operating in linux ^^

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**This is based on a linux mashine using the latest ffmpeg**

using the following code and changing only the -crf value you are able to create various video clip sizes.lower number is higher quality.

*The final video is compatible with all modern devices/services like native web players, ios devices , android devices, microsoft devices, ps3, xbox and more.*

```
ffmpeg
-y //overwrite the file if it exists

-i INPUTFILE // replace with the input file

-metadata title=THETITLE // set a nice title, visible on modern devices
-metadata date=THEDATE // set a nice title, visible on modern devices

-c:v libx264 // use the h264 codec
 -crf 21 // try different numbers between 18-26
 -preset veryslow // placebo,slow,fast,ultrafast==big file 
 -tune film // tune it a little
 -pix_fmt yuv420p // preferred on most modern devices
 -profile:v main // preferred on most modern devices
 -level 3.1 // preferred on most modern devices 
 -refs 4 // preferred on most modern devices

-c:a libfdk_aac // use aac
 -metadata:s:a language=eng // set a language, visible on modern devices 
 -b:a 128k // audio bitrate 128k is like mp3 192k
 -ar 48000 // 44100 ... whatever
 -ac 2 // audiochannels
 -movflags +faststart //move the metadata in the front of the video so it loads faster

OUTPUTFILE
```